# Git - error: RPC failed; HTTP 503 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Getting following error when i fetch, what might cause this issue and how can i resolve this.

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional- 
locks fetch --prune origin
 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
 error: RPC failed; HTTP 503 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 
503 Service Unavailable
Completed with errors, see above.
```

Comment: were you able to solve the issue ?

Comment: @Praveen - How did you solved this issue?

Comment: did anyone get a solution ?